# Парсинг с запоминанием последней точки

Tags: алгоритм, php

Есть лента, с которой я паршу последнии пару страниц ссылки на полные новости, в полных новостях я забираю описание и дополнительные характеристики, а ля комментарии, которые могут также добавляться время от времени.

Вопрос: как лучше отфильтровать те новости, которые уже были обработаны и те дополнения к новости, которые я уже спрарсил?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вариантов много все зависит от конкретной задачи, например:

Исходя из url: если вид url имеет вид http://site.ru/news.php?id=123 можно запоминать последнее значение id и записывать в файл, а при следующем проходе сравнивать эти значения и если значения будут меньше и равны этому id  то делать break;

Исходя из названия новости, получаем последние новости и если название новости равно тому которое мы запомнили break;

Тут главное выбрать какой удобнее, а придумать условий можно еще не один десяток!

Comment: Если с новостями то можно просто добавлять заголовок последней добавленной в файл и все что раньше нее не трогать потом. Меня больше волнуют комментарии, потому как если по такому же принципу действовать то получается много записей, и проблемно потом определять что нужно а что нет.

Comment: С комментариями нужно разбираться уже непосредственно видя их, многие платформы добавляют id в шапку комментария, но тут тоже могут возникнуть проблемы, комментарий могут отредактировать, тут нужно видеть что вы парсите, что-бы определить оптимальный вариант!

Comment: otvet.mail.ru паршу

Comment: Там в комменте есть такая ссылка http://otvet.mail.ru/answer/тут ид ответа/ вот и делайте проверку на равенство ей, как только совпало break;